# What is 'Effort' field in an Azure DevOps Epic?

Tags: azure-devops

What is the 'Effort' field in Azure DevOps? Is it an estimation in hours? Days? Something else?

What should I give as a value?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[It's a generic numeric field, your team gets to set the unit.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/scrum-process-workflow?view=azure-devops)

> Estimate the amount of work required to complete a PBI using any unit of measurement your team prefers, such as story points or time. A numeric value is required.

The [general guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/plan-track-work?view=azure-devops&tabs=basic-process) is to put in relative values using exponential scale or [Fibonacci scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_scale_(agile))

Comment: so, we should keep it basically like completed work + remaining work, right?

Comment: @MuhammedAydogan yep